# set key and values on array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have on array like: 
`$myarray = array("color", "red", "size", "big", "flavor", "bitter");` where color, size and flavor are the keys and the other are the values. How can I loop true the values only on the array.

I have a few arrays like that one so I only need to create a table and display their values like:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Color</th>
   <th>Size</th>
   <th>Flavor</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
       // I'm stuck here because I don't know how to get the values of each array
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Did you even **bother** to look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)?  Or look at a PHP tutorial that covers basic things like `foreach` loops?

Comment: YES ! but that page didn't show up on Google

Comment: [Wrong](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=epsugrst&gs_nf=1&tok=qrtfH5AQ5NgenBG_TbibEQ&cp=13&gs_id=1e&xhr=t&q=php+foreach+loop&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=php+foreach+l&aq=0P&aqi=g-P1g3&aql=f&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=87c6230bd8e448f1&biw=1599&bih=897).

Comment: I didn't type "php foreach loop" on Google, Sometimes people look for things that they don't know their name. Thanks for point out what to look and where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (list(, $key) = each($array)) {
    $value = current($array);
    next($array);

    echo $key, ': ', $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

But yes, you should really use a proper associative array instead of this makeshift solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your [syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is a little off; try an array like so:

```
$myarray=array(
    'color'=>'red',
    'size'=>'big',
    'flavor'=>'bitter'
);
```

And then you can grab the values like so:

```
$color=$myarray['color'];
$size=$myarray['size'];
$flavor=$myarray['flavor'];
```

Or with the array above, you could do a couple of loops:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
                $keys=array_keys($myarray);
                foreach($keys as $key) {
                    echo('<th>'.$key.'</th>');
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php
                foreach($myarray as $val) {
                    echo('<th>'.$val.'</th>');
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[array_keys() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
And here is a simple function to convert your array; although a bit crude, it handles everything just fine:

```
<?php
    function addKey($arr) {
        $newArr=array();
        $key=null;
        foreach($arr as $val) {
            if(!$key) {
                $key=$val;
            } else {
                $newArr[$key]=$val;
                $key=null;
            }
        }
        return($newArr);
    }
    $myarray=array('color','red','size','big','flavor','bitter');
    $myNewArray=addKey($myarray);
?>
```

Then in use, something like:

```
<?php
    foreach($myNewArray as $key=>$val) {
        echo('<p>Key: '.$key.'<br />Value: '.$val.'</p>');
    }
?>
```

Which will output:

```
Key: color
Value: red

Key: size
Value: big

Key: flavor
Value: bitter
```

Comment: That is great but the array is in the format that I pasted on the question. Is there any way to replace the spaces on the array with `=>` ?

Comment: Check my answer for a function to add keys to your current array; this function will only work if the order is one for one, as in, the input array goes (key,value,key,value,key,etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You are defining array incorrectly.

```
$myarray=array(
    'color'=>'red',
    'size'=>'big',
    'flavor'=>'bitter'
);
```

Then use it with foreach

```
foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {
   echo $key; //echoes the indexes like color
   echo $value; //echoes values like red
}
```